# Display selected categories from dropdown instead of all

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have the code below. I am using a drop-down based on `$category_id`. If I open the index page by default `$category_id=0`, so it displays all the categories in the index page. If I select the `$category_id=1` or `$category_id=2` or `$category_id=3` it works perfectly. What if `$category_id=0` to display none or display if some thing is set for `$category_id=0`?

Thanks in advance for your concern.

```
$tbl = new Grid;
if ($category_id) {
  $grids = $tbl->find_all('WHERE category_id = '.$category_id.' ORDER BY name');
} else {
  $grids = $tbl->find_all('ORDER BY display_order');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition:

```
if ($category_id)

return false for $category_id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your problem since you really haven't supplied much code, but it sounds like you don't want $category_id = 0 to be the default.

set the first option of your category dropdown to be -1

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="-1">All Categories</option>
    <option value="0">Category 0</option>
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

then your php would look like:

```
$tbl = new Grid;
if ($category_id > -1) {
    $grids = $tbl->find_all('WHERE category_id = '.$category_id.' ORDER BY name');
} else {
    $grids = $tbl->find_all('ORDER BY display_order');
}
```

Comment: index.php?&category_id=     this is my default code. if i select the dropdown my category_id=1,2,3.... it will work but by default it will show all the grids of 1,2,3....

Comment: If you want category_id=0 to not display anything. simply remove your 'else' statement.

Comment: If i remove else statement i got blank page.

Comment: What do you want it to display by default? That's what you code in your 'else' statement. right now your 'else' statement is loading the grid with everything by default. If that's not the behavior you want. Do something else here. Hide your grid and show a div that tells them to select a category from the dropdown or something.

Comment: I am a beginner, so could not able to crack it.. could you please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554262/dropdown-list-error-php-and-smarty?noredirect=1#comment52964565_32554262

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be adding the same question to SO again. You should update this question if you have more to add. Secondly, I can't help you with your Smarty template. I've never used it. I can only tell you that your else statement is what's causing you trouble. You have to build the display you want to show when your category_id = 0.